# Making ListView align items correctly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, tablelayout

I have a `ListView` with 10 columns and an header. As you can see in the following picture, the rows are not aligned with the header.
[image]

If the text in the TextViews was centered it seems like the problem would solve.
I tried many things, but none of them worked.

*NOTE: Please don't tell me to use a `TableLayout`. I already did it but the loading was much slower.

Here is the xml of the ListView:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/LinearLayout1"
        android:background="#d9d9d9" >

    </ListView>
```

Here is the list_header xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/header_back"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stockNumTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/stockNum"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shapeTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/shape"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weightTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/weight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clarityTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/clarity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cutGradeTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/cutGrade"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/labb"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/discountTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/disc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Here is the list_item xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stockNumTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/stockNum"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shapeTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/shape"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weightTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/weight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clarityTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/clarity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cutGradeTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/cutGrade"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/lab"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/discountTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/disc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
 </TableRow>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make textsizes the same for both header and items- you ddi 14sp for items and 16sp for header, and also remove margin from items, if the issue still keep same, put margin/padding to list items

Comment: The text sizes made better, but still, I want every list item to be centered under each header. I mean that let's say the status letter, should be centered under the Status header.

Comment: ah ok, then put this attribute in each list item, android:gravity="center_horizontal" or you can put it in as table row attribute, both ways should work out

Comment: as far as i see you put layout_weigth=1 to each of items, but never put android:weigthSum to main TableRow tag, put that attribute and as its value write the total of weights, that should work

Comment: one of the solutions I wrote should work out, nothing more comes up my mind :/